# Can I add include directories to the erl command?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

When compiling an erlang file with `erlc` I can add additional include directories like so:

```
erlc -I /home/trotter/code/open-source/yaws/include src/myapp.erl
```

When I'm compiling from within `erl` though, I don't see a way to do this on the command line. Instead, I have to do the following within the repl:

```
> compile:file("src/myapp", 
               [verbose,
                report_errors,
                {i,"/home/trotter/code/open-source/yaws/include"}]).
```

Is there a better way to do this that I don't know about, such as passing some command line argument to erl? If not, any suggestions for drying this up that *don't* require me to type nasty paths everytime I compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I rarely compile from the shell - only for small test scripts with `c(foo)`. My setup is this:

I have a build infrastructure. `make` builds the software (make is just a wrapper for `rebar` here). I can then build code from within `emacs` by hitting `F12` bound to the `compile` emacs command. In `vim` you can do the same with the `:make` command if my vim memory serves me (it has been a couple of years). Now this of course builds the code and throw it into an `ebin` dir.

The next step is to start Erlang with knowledge about the `ebin` dir:

```
 erl -pa ./ebin
```

which means that any reference to module `foo` goes and checks for `./ebin/foo.beam`. When I then figure out I have to fix some code, I fix it in the editor, compile the code with `F12` and then execute `l(foo)` in the shell which hot-loads the code.

It also has the advantage that any compilation error is now under the jurisdiction of the editor so I can quickly jump to the error and fix it.

Comment: Ok, that's totally a better solution to my problem. I did not know that I could use l(foo) to hot-load compiled code.

Comment: To make things easier, I created a .erlang file in the project root  with `code:add_patha("./dict").`. It added the "dict" path to the beginning of the path search list every time I run `erl` on that project.

Answer (score 2):

you can set `ERL_COMPILER_OPTIONS`.

see http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html

Comment: So would that work like this: ERL_COMPILER_OPTIONS='[{i,"/home/trotter/code/open-source/yaws/include"}]' erl ?